# Writing notes and highlighting in the Tanakh

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, chinuch-education, writing-printing, kavod

Is taking notes and highlighting in a Hebrew/English Tanakh considered defacing the text?

Answer (score 6):

So long as you aren't erasing the text, recording content-related notes in a text's margins is a very traditional Jewish practice. Consider this page from [a very old Tanakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_Codex):

[image: page from aleppo codex from book of kings showing many markings in the margins]

Comment: For the grammarians among us, I picked this page for a reason: who can spot Ben-Asher's 'typo'?

Comment: enlighten us please?

Comment: Would that be the extraneous dagesh in the lamed in אם־יש־לּי?

Comment: @magick ha that's a good answer, probably better than what I was thinking of. Cool that two seemingly distinct weird phenomena are so close within a couple lines of each other

Comment: @DoubleAA Aha, I see what you had in mind. Nice.

Comment: @magicker72 And the correct answer is? :)

Comment: @Kazibácsi The ḥataf-ḥiriq on לקחי.

Comment: @magicker72 Oh, I thought it was a feature and not a bug. It's also listed here (although it's not written like this in [MM](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c09a17.htm), [MG Keter](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/10/17)): https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Aleppo_Codex